# Название модуля, переводящего выражение в машинный код

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, помогите найти модуль, который при вводе любого выражения (число в н-ой степени, гиперболической функции и т.п.) переводил его в машинный код и находил значение в любой точке.

Comment: Когда-то, давным-давно я тоже задавал такой вопрос. Фигушки. Придется Вам писать собственный интерпретатор для выражений или где-нибудь стырить. Я тогда написал свой на QuickBasic'e. Давно живу! :-)

Comment: А стоимсоть такого модуля может кто-нибудь приблизительно подсказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стандартной поставке Delphi этого нет. В библиотеке [JCL](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library) есть парсер TEvaluator, который может вычислять математические выражения.

Answer (score 0):

По адресу http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx есть библиотека компонент со скриптовым бесплатным движком одна из функций, не припомню какая, требуемое делает. Закидываешь код в скрипт функции на языке PASCAL и вызываешь точно также как написанную в коде программы и многое другое...